# Xamarin.Forms Action Bar - Center Aligned Image

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin.Forms, how do I get the same effect as the application pictured below, specifically to show a centred image on the Action Bar / page tool bar (the section in a blue box)?
I would like to have a long width image in that section, and the solution must work for Android, iOS, Windows Phone, and Universal Windows (even if it means writing custom renderers or platform specific xamarin code).

[image]

Comment: You need to customize your actionbar/titlebar in the respective native projects. There is no cross platform solution. If its just this one page, you can try to hide the Navigation Title bar and have a layout with required items available inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create your own Xamarin.Forms view and handle the navigation by yourself something similar to this:

```
public class CustomBackNavigationBar : StackLayout
{
    public Image BackIcon;
    public Image Icon;
    public Label IconTitle;
    public StackLayout IconContainer;

    public CustomBackNavigationBar(string title, string icon)
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(15,5);
        HeightRequest = 40;
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        BackgroundColor = StaticData.BlueColor;
        Spacing = 15;

        BackIcon = new Image
        {
            Source = StaticData.BackIcon,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
        };

        Label Title = new Label
        {
            Text = title,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Default, typeof(Label)),
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        Icon = new Image
        {
            Source = icon
        };

        IconTitle = new Label
        {
            Text = StaticData.CallAgent,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)),
        };

        IconContainer = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
            Spacing = 2,
            Children = { Icon, IconTitle }
        };

        Children.Add(BackIcon);
        Children.Add(Title);
        Children.Add(IconContainer);

        #region Events

        BackIcon.GestureRecognizers.Clear();
        BackIcon.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(PopAsync)
        });

        #endregion

    }

    async void PopAsync()
    {
        await App.AppNavigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```